# I have a random letter appearing before my content. Where to start looking for the cause?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, theme-development, errors

Something weird is happening. I'm running Wordpress on a local DesktopServer. Suddenly, as in today, the letter "d" has started appearing before my content is random places.

In short, it appears on a line before my page content, above the site header. If I check the page source, the letter is immediately after the body tag. It happens on both content and admin pages.

The letter also appears at the beginning of a custom taxonomy list on the editor screen. If I start to enter a tag, something inserts the letter before the dropdown suggestions. If I'm typing "widget," I would enter the word as "dwidget."

I haven't installed any new plugins or themes recently, but I am writing a custom plugin, mostly to help a custom post type interface with a web API, but none of my recent changes have anything to do with the API.

I recently added a custom taxonomy, but I removed that from the code, and it didn't help the problem.

I'm using Pods for the custom post types, if that's relevant.

I'm not looking for answers, just some suggestions where to start looking for the cause (other than searching for every occurrence of the letter "d" in my code).

Comment: I've determined that the problem is connected to my custom plugin. When I enable it, I get the following message: 

"The plugin generated 1 character of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin."

Comment: The letter is immediately after which tag?  <body>?

Comment: Yes. the HTML shows <body class=".....">"d"

Comment: Are you enqueuing any scripts or styles with your custom plugin? If you are, look through that entire section to see if there's an errant "d" in there.  It sounds like what you have is an accidental keystroke (I had a cat mangle a site once with one paw swipe while I refilled my coffee) that is sitting outside of where it's supposed to be and your script enqueueing is taking that errant character and just placing it immediately within the body tag.

Comment: I don't do any enqueuing in the plug-in. All of that is done in the theme.

Comment: Are there any functions in your plugin that fire early before the header.php is loaded, that'd be the next place to check.

Comment: No. All the plugin does is take a number one custom field from a post, using that to query an external API, and then return that information after the post content. It has one class and a handful of shortcodes. Everything is firing inside the Loop as far as I can tell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107274/discussion-between-paul-and-tony-djukic).

Answer (score 0):

There was a "d" just before the opening php tag in one of my files. I'm a dork.